# how to store recently viewed products in cookie in php

Tags: php, cookies

I want to show recently viewed products in my application with the help of cookies in php.I m able to create a cookie and store it.But i m not aware about how to store viewed products in cookie and whenever user comes later on after first time.He should be able to see the recently viewed products if any.
Following is the code for cookie creation and checking the cookie name if exists..

```
<?php
session_start();
$ID=$_GET['id'];
echo $ID;
$array1=array();
$cookie=array();

if (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'])) {
    $cookie[] = $ID;
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['mycookie'];
    $cookie = unserialize($cookie);
} else {
    $cookie=array();
    $cookie[] = $ID;
    $cookie = serialize($cookie);
    // cookie not set, so let's "tag" this visitor
    setcookie('mycookie',$cookie);
    // display page for first time visitors
}
```

Please guide on how to show recently viewed products in addition to this cookie creation....

Comment: Just store the products IDs in a comma separated manner inside that cookie. Then, when the user returns, you have the list of IDs and can retrieve the products from your database.

Comment: Thanks.@arkascha-can u please help me on how to add product ids to cookie?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem here. In your example above you store a cookie called 'mycookie' with value '1'. All you have to do is replace the value '1' with a comma separated list of IDs: `setcookie('products',implode(',',$productIDs));`

Comment: k.k.gt that.so while retrieving the product ids from cookie.we need to use foreach loop and then we can pull data from database for product info..Right?Please correct me if i m wrong some where.

Comment: Absolutely correct. That is the standard approach, always go by the IDs.

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. Just one correction though, sorry for not mentioning it earlier. You should obviously _not_ retrieve single products by means of a foreach loop. Either use an `ìn` operator and the array of IDs as argument, or create a temporary table from the list of IDs and join that with the products table. This keeps you down to a single select statement which is much easier to handle when displaying the list of products.

Comment: Please check again sir.may b my syntax is incorrect.as it didnt work

Comment: No, that piece of code in its current state does not do anything useful. Don't get this wrong, but this looks like you never programmed before. Yet you claim: "I want to show ... in my application"... (is that really _your_ application?) I am afraid this busts the point of this board which is for answers to specific programming questions. My current impression is (again, don't get me wrong here, I may be wrong) that you are looking for a basic introduction to programming...

Comment: please please.dont be over excited bro.i was unable to put my complete code because of slow connection.Please check it now...

Comment: Sorry, you got me completely wrong. I am not exited about this at all. What I posted before is still valid. The code you provide suggests that you have no idea about php programming. So this isn't a specific question anymore. Answering it would mean I either have to write the whole code (after having dragged out all required details from you) or I'd have to give you a complete tutorial consisting of several lessons, tasks and checks. Again: don't get this wrong, I am not trying to be rude. But it simply is not possible to help you with such a general question in this board.

Comment: I strongly suggest you look for a good beginners tutorial on php programming on google and make your first easy steps. Then you can go on to more complex challenges like your cookie problem. But you cannot succeed to start  right in the middle. It won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your experience.i m developing php apps for long time...anyways..leave it..

Comment: Check this.
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?208135-Best-way-to-create-quot-recently-viewed-items-quot